# Upgrade version of Windows 7 without anytime upgrade key

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade

I recently did a clean install of Windows 7 on my machine.
My key is for Windows 7 Professional, but I mistakenly installed Home Premium onto the machine.
I've spent a day installing my various bits of software and settings, so I'd like to upgrade the system to Professional without having to reinstall, ideally.
When I look at Anytime Upgrade options, it expects me to have to purchase an upgrade key. As the system stands, it has *no* key and has not been activated.

Is there any way I can use my Professional key to perform an upgrade to Professional without a full reinstall?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Anytime Upgrade, when it asks for a key, use your retail key.